# vector matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Given that $u=(1, 1, 1)$, $v = (-2, 1, 0)$ and $w = (0, 3, 0)$, calculate the following (where possible):

```
(a) u . v
(b) u x v 
(c) (u x v) x w 
(d) (u . v) x w 
(e) u . (v x w)
```

Is $u \cdot v$ and $u \times v$ not the same thing?

Comment: Lots of googleing. not looking for someone to do it for me but a hint would be good. I am lost at where to started.

Comment: You could start by looking up  a definition of scalar product and vector product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is just using the definitions of dot product and cross product.

Namely, if $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, then $$u \cdot v = u_1v_1+u_2v_2+u_3v_3.$$

So the dot product of two vectors is a real number. However, the cross product is a new vector. Here is a formula:

$$ u \times v = (u_2v_3-u_3v_2,u_3v_1-u_1v_3,u_1v_2-v_1u_2).$$

You should be able to do it from here.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Look at the definitions of the [dot product ($\cdot$)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition) and the [cross product ($\times$)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation).